# Обход итератора через присвоение переменной Python

Tags: python

```
    for m in permutations("01", 1):
        for f in permutations("01", 1):
            print("m,f=", m, f)
```

Результат 4строчки

```
m,f= ('0',) ('0',) 

m,f= ('0',) ('1',) 

m,f= ('1',) ('0',) 

m,f= ('1',) ('1',)
```

Когда используем переменные то результат другой

```
    am=permutations("01", 1)
    af=permutations("01", 1)
    for m in am:
        for f in af:
            print("m,f=", m, f)
```

Результат такой. Всего 2строчки.

```
m,f= ('0',) ('0',) 

m,f= ('0',) ('1',)
```

Как используя переменные получить тот же результат?

Comment: af=permutations("01", 1) перенесите под первый for

Answer (score 0):

```
for m in permutations("01", 1):
        for f in permutations("01", 1):
            print("m,f=", m, f)
```

`permutations("01", 1)` создается на каждом шаге цикла по `m`, т.е. на каждом шаге `m` `permutations("01", 1)` выдаёт 2 значения (`0` и `1`)

```
am=permutations("01", 1)
af=permutations("01", 1)
for m in am:
    for f in af:
        print("m,f=", m, f)
```

`permutations("01", 1)` создается только 1 раз

в результате во втором случае вы вырабатываете 2 значения `0`, `1` уже на первом цикле `m` и af оказывается "пустым" (достигнут конец), поэтому на втором цикле `m` цикл по `f` уже не происходит

Answer (score 0):

Заменил код на

```
am=permutations(str_m, count_m)
for m in am:
    af = permutations(str_f, count_f)
    for f in af:
        print("m,f=", m, f)
```

Заработало так, как надо. Спасибо Zhihar